# Is there a Polymer component that simplifies communications with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, polymer

Given the promise Polymer and web components have in simplifying development I am wondering if anyone has developed a wrapper component that simplifies talking to a MongoDB backend? Does anyone know of one?

Is this a sane idea? I guess it would need a custom server-side piece, but even so, I expected that lots of people would have written one, but I cannot find any; or is this a case where there are so many options that I should write my own node/express/mongo server?

Or is it that the AJAX component will do all the heavy lifting and I just need to use that?

Puzzled Andy

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Like a web component that provides an interface for you to manage mongodb collections on the backend? There are object relational mappers (ORMs) for MongoDB such as Mongoose, but I don't think that's what you're asking is it?

Comment: Not really, I was looking for something that encapsulates using the REST or native api's so you dont need to understand those things. I guess it would function a bit like a db cursor or something. dfreedm's suggestion to look at the firebase component is a good one, for some reason I though firebase was local only, but i see now that it is not. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use Strongloop/Loopback (http://loopback.io/getting-started/) as backend and do ajax request thought Fetch (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).
Unfortunally Fetch isn't fully supported in all browser but thanks to this  polyfill (https://github.com/github/fetch) you can have a full supported fallback solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unaware of a MongoDB element, but perhaps you could use the Polymer firebase element as a reference.

https://github.com/polymer/firebase-element

Comment: It should be a good starting point, and I may indeed go ahead and have a bash. I was rather hoping that someone else had done the hard work though :) Thx.

Comment: I think maybe I'll just switch to firebase, looks like it does what i want :P

Comment: What has been your experience with Polymer + Firebase Andrew? Thanks ;) Did you find a nice mongodb connect for polymer? ;)