# How can I use mongoDB as back end for polymer?

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am pretty new at learning Polymer, but I was wondering if I can use MongoDB as a back-end in Polymer. Maybe somehow using 'core-ajax' element.
I looked around for answers and I found one that suggested using Firebase element. : https://github.com/polymer/firebase-element

Is there any simpler way? Like the one nodeJS-express offers?

Also, can I use the json doc served by express using Mongo as an input JSON for 'core-ajax' of polymer? I tried doing  it by throwing out the JSON output at certain route and passing that route as an URL to 'core-ajax'. But it failed. Why?

Comment: This seems like two questions in one, the first is covered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688291/is-there-a-polymer-component-that-simplifies-communications-with-mongodb (to which I think the answer is that there isn't one yet). The second question doesn't have enough information for anyone to answer. Can you clarify it, perhaps by giving a snippet of code that shows how you're using core-ajax and how it's failing?

Comment: From the docs on Polymer, core ajax is what connects to a data-source.
` <core-ajax id="ajax"
      auto
      url="../api/posts.json"
      on-core-response="{{postsLoaded}}"
      handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>`

Comment: Sorry about the previous commenting attempt.
From the docs on Polymer, core ajax is what connects to a data-source.
`core-ajax id="ajax"
auto
url="../api/posts.json"
on-core-response={{postsLoaded}}
handleAs="json">`
IN this case, the core-ajax will connect to a json file called 'posts.json' at given URL. And this works. But however when I try to connect it to a local server, say 'http://localhost:3000/posts/json' where I'm giving a JSON output directly from mongoDB via express, the core-ajax doesn't seem to recognise that.

Comment: It could be a few things, but one thing I notice is that you're missing the scheme for your url. Try `"http://localhost:3000/posts/json"`

Comment: I managed get it working! 
Apparently I had to set the header of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to my local server manually. And it worked. :D 
I appreciate your time Peter. :)

Comment: **PWAs & Polymer: Let's Prototype a Modern Web App:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atql00KNdsQ